# Can you join on a variable name that you define using `as` (in SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

This works:

```
select
    x.long_name as ln
from x
join y on y.ln = x.long_name
```

This doesn't:

```
select
    x.long_name as ln
from x
join y on y.ln = x.ln
```

can it be made to work somehow?  In a way that is simple and compact?  It'd be convenient because I'm generating filter tables (`y` would be a filter table) and queries programmatically.

Comment: Either of the two answers are what you would need. You can't reference an aliased column by name in a join predicate.

Comment: An alternative would be don't give your columns long names, if typing the name is that difficult.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `apply` to define the alias in the `from` clause:

```
select v.ln
from x cross apply
     (values (x.long_name)) v(ln) join
     y
     on y.ln = v.ln
```

Other alternatives are subqueries and CTEs.

Comment: cool (+1) but too verbose.  would be simpler for me to add another argument with the long name to my query-generating function

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use a "table expression" to use a column from a "result set".

```
select *
from ( -- here we create a table expression named "z"
  select
    long_name as ln
  from x
) z
join y on y.ln = z.ln
```

As you see the table expression "z" has the column you want.

Comment: cool thanks (+1) but looking for something more compact, if it exists

Comment: @generic_user Not in the SQL standard at least.